# How to find everything before and after a special tag or id

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I want to remove everything before and after `form`. I am new in jquery and English.

```
<h1>hello</h1>
<span>world</span>
<form id=f>
<input name=g>
<input type=submit>
</form>
<div>footer</div>
<p>more</p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd go for:

```
var el = $('#f').detach();
$('body').empty().append(el);
```

i.e. take the bits out of the DOM that you want to keep, and then completely replace the current body with those elements.  This will ensure it works even if the elements you want are nested a long way down the DOM tree.

See http://jsfiddle.net/rwWp9/1/

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.nextAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/) and [`.prevAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/prevAll/) to select everything after and before an element.

```
$("form#f").nextAll().remove();
$("form#f").prevAll().remove();
```

**Example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/pzWEW/) of your markup.**

Comment: This assumes no ancestors wrapping the content in question.

Comment: NB: will only work if the tag you're selecting on is at the "top" level of the hierarchy (i.e. directly under `<body>`).

Comment: and `$(el).siblings().remove()` would have been neater.

Answer (score 0):

Check out jQuery functions [not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/), [prevUntil()](http://api.jquery.com/prevUntil/) and [nextUntil()](http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/).  Also [next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/), [prev()](http://api.jquery.com/prev/), and [parentsUntil()](http://api.jquery.com/parentsUntil/) might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You must use nextAll() and prevAll() methods to remove all the siblings. However, just to give you an alternative idea take a look at this code. Please note that it's not the solution.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("body").children().each(function(i){
   if($(this).attr("id") != "f"){
        $(this).remove();
    }
});
});
```